# TypeError: string indices must be integers with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare 2 dataframe rows to eachother. When I try to run my code I get this error:
TypeError: string indices must be integers.

this is my code:

```
for item in df:
    if item["comment text"] != item["original text"]:
        counter1 += 1
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: item is a string not a dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)() function to iterate through a Pandas DataFrame

```py
for index,item in data.iterrows():
    if item["comment text"] != item["original text"]:
        counter1 += 1
```

Comment: _You need to use the iterrows() function to iterate through a Pandas DataFrame_ Not only do you not **need** to use `iterrows()`, you really shouldn't.

Comment: @AMC Do you mean itertuples would be better for his case?

Comment: `itertuples()` is one option, yes, although I think it's important to mention that explicitly looping over a DataFrame is unidiomatic and rarely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

If df is a DataFrame, you iterate it wrongly (the right way is `for i_row, row in df.iterrows():...`
On the other hand, it's unclear what exactly you want to compare with what. As for me, the problem isn't posed clearly.